# Error: Conversion to TensorType from function variable in Python code

Tags: python, type-conversion, tensor

I've been trying the Kaggle Blackhole Dataset example that has been explained in Cameron Davidson-Pilon's book 'Bayesian Methods for Hackers' in Chapter 5. However, I have been having difficulty in using the `pymc3` package and its functions. The priors have been defined as uniform distributions and that is working fine. So is the function `meean` that is defined after. But I have been running into an error when I tried the normal distribution, which states that a function cannot be converted to TensorType. Where am I going wrong? Please find my code below:

```
def euc_dist(x,y):
    return np.sqrt(((x-y)**2).sum(axis=1))

def f_dist(gxy_pos,halo_pos,c):
    return np.maximum(euc_dist(gxy_pos,halo_pos),c)[:,None]

def tan_dist(glxy_pos,halo_pos):
    delta=glxy_pos-halo_pos
    t=(2*np.arctan(delta[:,1]/delta[:,0]))[:,None]
    return np.concatenate([-np.cos(t),-np.sin(t)],axis=1)

import pymc3 as pm
with pm.Model() as model:
    mass_large = pm.Uniform('mass_large',40,180)
    halo = pm.Uniform('halo',0,4200)

def meean(mass=mass_large,h_pos=halo,glx_pos=data[:,:2]):
    return mass/f_dist(glx_pos,h_pos,240)*tan_dist(glx_pos,h_pos)

mn=pm.Deterministic('mean',meean)

ellpty=pm.Normal('ellipticity',meean,1./0.05,observed=data[:,2:])
```

Error:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\basic.py in as_tensor_variable(x, name, ndim)
    198         except Exception:
    199             str_x = repr(x)
--> 200         raise AsTensorError("Cannot convert %s to TensorType" % str_x, type(x))
    201 
    202 # this has a different name, because _as_tensor_variable is the

AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert <function meean at 0x000002CD7113BD90> to TensorType', <class 'function'>)
```